# How to change class on checked multiple checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, checkbox

I have some list of checkboxes, they're in classic `ng-repeat`. I wish to change class of label on checking my checkboxes individually. Right now i have all checkboxes with `checked` class. What is wrong?

```
<fieldset class="g-checkbox_square_big box-inline-full_width-relative">
    <label class="box-full_width-grid-vertical_align_middle" ng-class="{checked: 'area_selected_' + area.id}">
        <div class="g-checkbox-dummy"></div>
        <img src="{{area.icon.icon.small.url === null ? '/public/images/image-placeholder.svg': area.icon.icon.small.url}}" class="shift-padding_2-horizontal" alt="Area Image">
        <span class="text-size_big-color_appblue">{{ area.title }}</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-bind-model="'area_selected_' + area.id" data-id="{{area.id}}"/>
</fieldset>
```

FYI : The input is covering all dummy checkbox space.

Comment: Ca you elaborate _change class of label on checking my checkboxes individually._?

Comment: click on input - change it state = change class of sibling label

Comment: create new function to change status of your `area` object and call that function on `ng-change` of your checkbox

Comment: there is no way to manipulate it without the controller integration?

Comment: can you try replacing area.id in <input> and label fields with {{area.id}}

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without controller changes

```
<fieldset class="g-checkbox_square_big box-inline-full_width-relative">
    <label class="box-full_width-grid-vertical_align_middle" ng-class="area.checked?'checked':''">
        <div class="g-checkbox-dummy"></div>
        <img src="{{area.icon.icon.small.url === null ? '/public/images/image-placeholder.svg': area.icon.icon.small.url}}" class="shift-padding_2-horizontal" alt="Area Image">
        <span class="text-size_big-color_appblue">{{ area.title }}</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-bind-model="area.checked" data-id="{{area.id}}" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<fieldset class="g-checkbox_square_big box-inline-full_width-relative">
<label class="box-full_width-grid-vertical_align_middle" ng-class="{checked: area_selected_{{area.id}}}">
    <div class="g-checkbox-dummy"></div>
    <img src="{{area.icon.icon.small.url === null ? '/public/images/image-placeholder.svg': area.icon.icon.small.url}}" class="shift-padding_2-horizontal" alt="Area Image">
    <span class="text-size_big-color_appblue">{{ area.title }}</span>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-bind-model="area_selected_{{area.id}}" data-id="{{area.id}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer without interacting with controller, as you needed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.checked
{
background: blue;
}
</style>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="areas=['1','2','3']">
  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="area in areas">
      <label ng-class="{checked: show}">{{'area'+area}}
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-bind-model="'area' + area" ng-click="show = !show"/>
</fieldset>
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**HEre is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CMEqXK9nXOqMmlYaS7tl?p=preview)